# Right to left controls in Windows Applications!

Tags: c#, controls, windows

i am a new windows application programmer and have a right-to-left language.
i want write my own app in rtl lang. how can i perform this?
should i set RightToLeft peroperty for any controls in forms to Yes or true?? this is very harmful!!
can I set something to convert and set controls to rtl? can i do some settings in "Settings.settings" file in properties folder?

Comment: Why is settings the RightToLeft property "harmful"?

Comment: I'm wondering the same as William.  Is there an almost famous article called "RightToLeft Considered Harmful" I haven't read yet?

Comment: you know in a registration form for example we have many controls: text boxes, labels, buttons,... and all of them must be in rtl format. and think about 10 forms in an application. is not harmful??
in web applications we have CSS files that we can do this very easy to hole of a web application. but in win application how can do taht?

Answer (score 1):

The [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) control arranges its contents in a horizontal or vertical flow direction. The FlowLayoutPanel control correctly reverses its flow direction in right-to-left (RTL) layouts. Any Windows Forms control, including other instances of FlowLayoutPanel, can be a child of the FlowLayoutPanel control.  Given this, you should be able to control the flow direction of all of your controls with a single setting, provided they reside within a FlowLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Just set

```
RightToLeft = true
```

for any control where this is important (anything containing text I imagine)

Answer (score 0):

See MSDN documentation for [Control.RightToLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft(vs.71).aspx) and [Ambient Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties(VS.71).aspx)

All you really have to do is set it on your form and its controls should take care of themselves.  It's apparent on the simple case of a TextBox on a Form where the Form's RightToLeft property is set to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way ever is to add these two lines:

```
this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
this.RightToLeftLayout = true;
```

Under this line (you will find it there already):

```
InitializeComponent();
```